# Constant conditional variance

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditioning, conditional-variance

Let $X$ and $U$ be two independent random variables, and let $Z= X+U$.  Under which conditions is $Var(X|Z)$ constant?  I know this holds for instance when $X$ and $Z$ are jointly normal. I'm interested if there is a more general result regarding this.